# Generate a list in customer journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, list

I'm wondering if exists a way to generate a list of subscribers at a certain point of the customer journey to retrieve customers arrived to that point and their individual engagement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do so, but there are a few possibilities you might want to consider:

- Create a data extension for your journey and add a few *Update Contact activities* to your journey that write the position, along with other data to the data extension.
- If you are only interested in engagement to email activities for example, you could extract the data using an automation containing a *SQL query activity* (useful data views might be `_Sent`, `_Click`, `_Open`, `_Journey` and `_JourneyActivity`)

**Related documentation:**

- [Journey Builder - Update a Contact](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/update_a_contact/)
- [Automation Studio - Query: Journey Builder Sends in Last 24 Hours](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours/)
- [Automation Studio - Data Views](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/)